# How to unit test a method with void return type?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How do you write a unit test for a method with void return type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing void methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246038/unit-testing-void-methods)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit testing void methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246038/unit-testing-void-methods)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the method does *something*, you can try to sense that *something*.

That is, suppose it increments a variable that is exposed elsewhere in a property - you can check the value of the property before and after calling the method.

In essence this is checking that the method is working correctly by checking the expected side-effects from it.