# How to unit test a method returning void?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, void

I am doing unit test(C#) and i have some methods which are returning void.I want to know what is the best way to mock those methods ?

Below is the piece of code:-

```
 public void DeleteProduct(int pId)
 {
         _productDal.DeleteProduct(pId);
 }
```

Comment: You don't 'mock' methods of the unit you want to test. You may need to mock some of its dependencies though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing void methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246038/unit-testing-void-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could test is that ProductDAL.DeleteProduct is called with the correct parameters. 
This can be accomplished by using dependency injection and mocks!

Sample using [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) as mocking framework:

```
public interface IProductDal
{
    void DeleteProduct(int id);
}

public class MyService
{
    private IProductDal _productDal;

    public MyService(IProductDal productDal)
    {
        if (productDal == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("productDal"); }
        _productDal = productDal;
    }

    public void DeleteProduct(int id)
    {
        _productDal.DeleteProduct(id);
    }
}
```

Unit test

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeleteProduct_ValidProductId_DeletedProductInDAL()
{
    var productId = 35;

    //arrange
    var mockProductDal = new Mock<IProductDal>();
    var sut = new MyService(mockProductDal.Object);

    //act
    sut.DeleteProduct(productId);

    //assert
    //verify that product dal was called with the correct parameter
    mockProductDal.Verify(i => i.DeleteProduct(productId));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you can mock the field `_productDal`, you have to test if the record/object with the corresponding `pId` was actually deleted.

The mocking of `_productDal` can be achieved if you inject it in your class, for instance using [constructor injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: I would say its very bad practise to mock the dependencies like a database!!

Comment: @Neel And why is that? Mocking is something you only do for testing purposes. And if you want to **test** this method, then looking at the body of the method and concluding that all it does is 'forward' the call to the `_productDal` field, then all you have to test is that the `_productDal` is actually receiving the call. Which you can verify if you **mock** that object.

Comment: @Neel mocking its just for untestable dependency, like file system, database, etc...