# Unit Testing a Service without a return type

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to follow a `TTD` approach to building a new `Email Service`. The service will have a number of methods that form a "pipeline" of sorts, in that they receive an `object`, perform some actions on the `object` then pass it over to the next service.

Is there a way to unit test these methods individually?

Example of one method:

```
public void RecieveMessage(string message)
{
    var @event = JsonAdapter.ToObject<RecievedEvent>(message);

    if(@event.IsValid())
    {
        CreateTemplates(@event);
    }
    else
    {
        Log("Warn", "Invalid message received");
    }
}
```

Can this be tested? Do I need to rethink my approach? Should I tests the methods together?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `EventHandlerMethod`? A specific method or a delegate of some kind? If the latter, that's how you test this method - you mock the delegate and check that it's called with an appropriate value.

Comment: Can you mock Log method to check if warn was return or not?

Comment: Your likely going to need a mocking engine like [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq/) to achieve the above. You can do this without but mocking engines include methods specifically for this kind of thing.

Comment: The EventHandlerMethod (CreateTemplates) is simply a method that creates the appropriate templates for emails based on the type of event coming in. I will change the name to be more clear, was trying to be a bit more generic than my code. @Liam Thank you I will look into Moq!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit testing void methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246038/unit-testing-void-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do what I asked following the answer to another question linked above in the comments to the original about Unit Testing View Methods.

However the real answer to my question is that a different approach should be looked at, working from a TDD basis I should be looking for a testable solution, rather than creating a solution and looking for ways to test it.