# How do I unit test a Command Handler that returns a void?

Tags: c#, cqrs

Please see the code below:

```
public class CreatePersonHandler
        : IRequestHandler<CreatePersonCommand,Unit>
    {

 public async Task<Unit> Handle(CreatePersonCommand message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var person = _enquiryFactory.Create(message.Gender, message.Salary);
            var offers = getAvailableOffers(); 
            person.AssignOffers(offers);
            await _mediator.DispatchDomainEventsAsync(person);
            return Unit.Value;
        }
  }
```

**Notice that:**

> 1) The command does not have any state.
>   2) The command method
>   has no return value.

I have read a few similar questions on here e.g. this one: [Unit testing void methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246038/unit-testing-void-methods).  Are CQRS command handlers that return voids classed as informational and should not be unit tested?

Comment: It has side effects that you're probably interested in confirming, though. I'd think you want to check the events you expect are dispatched when this is executed.

Comment: You should be able to mock and set expectations on your service interactions (Create, getAvailableOffers, AssignOffers)

Comment: @Charles Mager/@ChrisBint, is it a bad idea to just have return true on the last line and have it return a bool.  It would be so much easier.

Comment: What would testing that prove? The implementation could simply be `return true` and it'd still pass.

Comment: @Charles Mager, I guess I would not mock the _mediator class? I would let the method call _mediator.DispatchDomainEventsAsync?

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, testing a "command handler" that returns a void is no different from testing a method that returns a void -- the void return is a clear indication that the method is invoked for its side effects, so you check for those.

- Katrina Owen [467 tests, 0 failures, 0 confidence](https://vimeo.com/68730418)
- Sandi Metz [The Magic Tricks of Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M)

Depending on the nature of the subject under test, it may make sense to use a [test double](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html), rather than a live collaborator, to determine whether or not the right thing happened.

```
var person = _enquiryFactory.Create(message.Gender, message.Salary);
var offers = getAvailableOffers(); 
person.AssignOffers(offers);
await _mediator.DispatchDomainEventsAsync(person);
return Unit.Value;
```

One thing to notice in this example is that, not only is there no *state* in your handler, but there is also no *logic* -- any branching here is encapsulated within the collaborators.

Assuming the pieces fit together, there's not a lot that can fail that is the responsibility of the handler.  So I wouldn't block a pull request like this because there wasn't a "unit test" for the handler.

> Could you clarify what you mean by: "Assuming the pieces fit together". I

In a "strongly typed" language, we would get a lot of checking done for us by the compiler/interpreter.  If the type system isn't satisfied, then we are going to get an error message before the method is loaded into the execution environment.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you clarify what you mean by: "Assuming the pieces fit together".  I will watch the videos later.

Comment: I am using c# so I guess all the pieces do fit togetther?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are adding/raising new events using .DispatchDomainEventsAsync(). Instead of returning nothing, you can return these events and write a simple unit test to count the number or structure these events.